# JavaScript - add a object to an array when index is unknown?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have an array

> var prices = ['100','200','300','500'];

i'm trying to insert a price if one condition apply,

```
var index = prices.indexOf(400);

if(index){  
       prices.splice(1, 0, '150'); 
         };



var index2 = prices.indexOf(200);

    if(index2){  
           prices.splice(3, 0, '600'); 
              };
```

Now my problem is i need to insert `'600'` after the `'300'`. but, if 1st condition happened the index which i need to insert value `'600'` would be change. in this situtation how can i add `'600'` after the `'300'`?

**Update**

if 1st condition occurs the array have to be,

> // ['100','150','200','300','600','500']

if not ,

> // ['100','200','300','600','500']

Comment: After insertion, you have to sort the array

Comment: can please give me a sample.

Comment: Sorry, one thing I want to know that, you want the array should in ascending / descending order?

Comment: array should be in static.. dont need to be in any order

Comment: please add some use cases. btw, the first `indexOf` returns `-1`, which is a truthy value in the condition. please add what you really want.

Comment: is the index fixed initially?  What i'll suggest is to `increment count` whenever insertion something is added to the list and then add in that array with original `index + count`(no of insertions till now)

Comment: @NinaScholz if first condition occurs or not, i need to add `600` after the `300`.

Comment: please add `imageList` and the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz am really sorry for the inconvenience. That is prices only, not the imageList.  Sorry again

Comment: it would be really helpfull, if you add the array, what you are looking for, which index do you want and how the array looks after the inserting looks like for both cases. actually it looks hrdcoded custom inserting, without rulable conditions.

Comment: @NinaScholz i have updated those details. Can you please have a look

Comment: some annotations. `indexOf` works strict. it does not find numbers in an array of strings. in *update*, `'600'` is not in the array, why here? `indexOf` returns `-1` id the value is not in the array. any check, which does not checks `-1` does not return a reliable result.

Answer (score 0):

html =>

```
<div id="demo"> </div>
```

javascript =>

```
var prices = ['100','200','300','500'];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = prices;

function myFunction() {

    var index = prices.indexOf('400');
    if(index >= 0){
        prices.splice(1, 0, '150'); 
    }

    index = prices.indexOf('300');

    if(index >= 0){
        prices.splice(index + 1, 0, '600'); 

    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = prices;

}
```